# Method invocation vs method execution

Tags: java

Is there a difference between method invocation time and method execution time. I think we can easily measure method execution time. But how can i measure the method invocation time. 
Would it be different each time. (Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking a method and executing a method are synonyms - they are they same thing.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Okay , so what it means that if I have to measure how long each invocation of a particular method takes then that means the time a method takes to execute. So if i measure the time before invoking a method and after the method returns and then calculate the difference that gives me the method invocation/ or method execution time.

Comment: invocation is calling the method, once you're inside the method execution occurs.

Comment: that means both are different.. how can we measure the method invocation time..I mean if i call some method of a class say add(int x, int y) what could be the method invocation time..i mean i just called the method and that means the method will be invoked immediately..What factors would count towards the time in method invocation?

Comment: @kd44: Nothing happens "immediately". See my answer for how different types of methods are invoked differently.

Comment: how can i measure the invocation time then?

Answer (score 4):

*Invocation time* is the time required to invoke or call the method. *Execution time* is the time required to execute the body of the method.

See [7.7 Invoking Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Compiling.doc.html#14787) and [Instruction Set](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html) in the JVM spec. There are 4 different ways in which Java methods can be invoked:

1. `invokevirtual` - used for class method calls
2. `invokeinterface` - used for interface method calls
3. `invokestatic` - used for static methods
4. `invokespecial` - used for constructors, private methods and `super` calls

`invokestatic` is usually the fastest because it is tied to a specific class while the others can be relatively slower. `invokeinterface` is possibly the slowest because classes can implement multiple interfaces and the correct method must be resolved.

Different invocations of the same method will take the same time.

Comment: That leads me to an interesting question.  Java's security relies on the VM.  So can you use `invokestatic` to invoke the base class version of a derived class' method?  If so, that seems like a possible security hole.

Comment: @Omnifarious: To do that, you would have to modify the `.class` file, and I don't see that as a security hole in the VM.

Comment: Couldn't you create a `.class` file with a new class that called `invokestatic` on the methods of some other class?

Comment: @Omnifarious: Sure you could, but that's equivalent to writing a simple Java program to call the static method - always possible, not a security hole. :) Of course, if you manually change the `.class` file but the method doesn't exist or is not static, the JVM will throw a linkage error.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that makes sense.  I think, in order to answer the question percolating in my mind in more detail I will have to read up on the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

invocation = execution  --->  invocation time = execution time.