# Are Method Call and Method execution different things?

Tags: function, methods, semantics

I did see this post: [Method invocation vs method execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235628/method-invocation-vs-method-execution) but to me it does not quite make sense. I thought in order to execute the method, we must call the method, but both are two separate things in my opinion. The execution of the method is separate thing than the method call itself. I am unable to see how they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overthinking about it.

*Calling* a method or a method getting *executed* are the exact same thing.
Or you could say, a method gets executed when it gets called.

**Eg:**

*calling the method here*

```
int x = returnThatInteger();
```

*some where else in the code*

```
public int returnThatInteger(){    // method executing here 
    return 1;
}
```

So you're right,

> in order to execute the method, we must call the method